# Help/guide to design over 1 mA current circuit with 5000 Vrms and 150°C operating conditions

Tags: amplifier, integrated-circuit, power-electronics, current-limiting, switch-lifetime

I am designing an over 1 mA current detector circuit using IN193 with a supply voltage of 5000 Vrms to the test sample IC at 150°C temperature as shown in the attached figure.

I expect that circuit is not so good and accurate. Can anybody help/ guide me to design a circuit which indicates over 1mA current for the above-given conditions and shown test setup?

[image: C]

Comment: You are generally better off measuring current in the Ground side of your circuit if you can.

Comment: Welcome. How do you plan to generate 5 KV without hurting yourself?

Comment: @ Sparky256 we have test high voltage source so that's not an issue. The issue is to design a current indicating circuit

Comment: @ elchambro any idea or circuit ? or weblink which could help me?

Comment: _"I guess that circuit is not so good and accurate."_ - it's not even a circuit. How accurate does it need to be, and what sort of indication do you need?

Comment: I just need help of how I can design 1mA over current alarming circuit. If someone have some web-link or suggestion that would be really approciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you crop your image? 90% of it is white space. Your test circuit doesn't have to be in the 150°C area so that is not relevant to your question.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is to limit over-current for the circuit operating at 150 degrees C oven and the applied voltage can go as far as 5000Vrms. Since you have asked only for indication, not tripping, I will provide you the explanation for indication only.

According to these specifications,
when working at these, high voltage, it is usually advised to use a hall-effect current sensor to detect current (safety purposes, and instrument safety.) Hall sensors are available to detect within a specified range (although 1mA range is very low.)

5000V is too high for a current sensor to be connected in series connection.

Comment: Actually I never used a hall sensor before. Could you give me an example that can help me to use it with my stated objective?. In addition, which hall effect sensor I can use for the given specs? what will you suggest if I also want to trip my circuit?